# Solutions to wave equations

Tags: transmission-line, math, physics

In the following steps for a solution to the Telegrapher's equations, I don't understand how equation 9.17 follows from 9.16. Substituting in \$\gamma\$ as given, it seems that the result should be \$g(x,t)\propto e^{j\omega t} e^{\pm j \alpha} e^{\pm \beta z}\$, so the difference is whether the alpha or beta exponentials have a \$j\$ in them.

Since my understanding is that alpha and beta must be real this can't be just a matter of defining them such that equation 9.17 holds.

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source. Try to compare this derivation to one given in another source.

Comment: @AJN The source is the book "Electromagnetics for High-speed Analog and Digital Communication Circuits" by Ali Niknejad, chapter 9 (Transmission lines) page 251. I also referenced the material in Engineering Electromagnetics by Inan & Inan, but they don't seem to have this particular formulation.

Comment: Context [from google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=o80zzb4AUNYC&lpg=PR4&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q&f=false) for others visiting.

Comment: Looks like a typo. from 9.14 to 9.15, \$\gamma\$ gains a \$\jmath\$.

Comment: @AJN Thanks for the response - I was also able to find another reference to these derivations in [lecture slides by the book's author, located here](http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/ee117/pdf/lecture3.pdf) (slide 22). The slides have the same result, it looks like the setup is a bit different but I'm not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: Looking at slide 21 and 22, I can't locate eq 9.15. But I can locate 9.17, 9.16, 9.14. So 9.15 is probably a typo in the book.

Comment: @AJN Seems to be most likely. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The author is a teacher at a university it seems. You can try emailing him.